# Angular 4 interceptor not setting headers

Tags: angular, http, typescript, cors

For some reason the headers on my http request are not beeing sent.

I am using one interceptor with the following code.

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');

      if (token) {
          req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

After seeing the received headers on the api there is no authorization header.

I don´t know if i am doing something wrong on the API side. I have the following cors configuration.

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
};
```

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry. I am now seeing that some things are not properly formatted.

Comment: did you solved this? i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I set the authorization header like this :

```
  @Injectable()
    export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor() { }
        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');

            if (token) {
                req = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });

                return next.handle(req);
            }
        }
```